# UWP SQLite concurrency clarification

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp, win-universal-app, sqlite-net

On my UWP app, I have a class named DBContext which provides a live connection to an SQLite DB on a singleton manner. I have a few heavy DB write statements to execute periodically which might take more than 10 seconds to complete.

My question is what happens when 1 thread is asking for a connection and my DBContext will provide it and that connection starts a transaction which takes 10 seconds to finish.

Now assume another thread also is asking for a connection and my DBContext class will return the same connection which created for the above task (Since it's a singleton) and this thread also use the same connection and try to write to the same SQLite DB?

NOTE: This is an actual scenario and I'm getting 'Busy' and 'DB locked' exceptions from SQLite. Please let me know a good approach to access the DB in a good manner including best practices of using SQLite in UWP.

NOTE: WAL mode also enabled in SQLite but still gets the 'Busy' exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look for EF.Core with SQLite

Comment: I have to support early versions than 'Fall creators update'. So I can't use EF core. My using SQLite-Net on my app.

Comment: **EntityFramework** supported early version than 16299. Please refer this [blog](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/getting-started-with-sqlite-and-entity-framework-on-uwp/), and this is code [sample](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-SQLite-EntityFramework-Sample)